# Maven can't be found after install of another Java JDK

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I had java8 and maven3 installed on my Ubuntu 64bits.
I added java7 (but didn't remove java8) and configured my system as explained in [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JRE-on-Ubuntu-Linux).
(I edited the path of java7 in /etc/profile and I used "update-alternatives" command to inform Ubuntu where my Java JRE is located and that it is my default JRE).

Java7 install was fine and I get:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_75
```

But after this, maven doesn't work anymore:

```
mvn -version
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Does someone know how to solve this? Because I am sure that I still have maven.

Comment: Where is the `mvn` executable from `maven3` installed? How does your `PATH` setting look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed maven with apt-get install maven (so I am not sure where is the executable), my path looks like: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/bin

Comment: Could you check if maven is still installed. `dpkg -l "maven*"`. If not, reinstallation should solve the problem.

Comment: for dpkg -l maven, I get: Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  maven2         <none>       <none>       (no description available)

Comment: I tried to remove maven with sudo apt-get purge maven3, and got "Unable to locate package maven3". But I checked that I still have .m2 directory and maven directory in /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check following points

Is this maven 3?

```
I installed maven with apt-get install maven
```

Was maven 2 installed before?

```
un maven2 <none> <none> (no description available)
```

Is maven 3 available in the Ubuntu repository?

```
sudo apt-get purge maven3
Unable to locate package maven3
```

Seems you have installed maven 3 not from the repository

```
/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.1
```

To get it working add the location of `mvn` to your `PATH` (put this in your user profile script)

```
export PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.1/bin/:${PATH}
mvn -version
```

Comment: I added the mvn location to the path as you mentionned and Maven works again. Thanks!